# php dependency injection with a container

Tags: php, dependency-injection, containers

I'm developing a PHP framework for educational purposes. I have learned a lot since I started it.

I've decided how I'm going to deal with dependencies. I'm create a simple DI Container.

---

My **first** question is not about the DI Container itself, but how to inject objects that are created outside (before the DI Container).

**Q:** In the example: I am calling `container->manualAdd('_logger', $logger);`. Is there another way to accomplish this? Am I breaking the idea of DI Container?

---

My **second** question is about hooking functions. So when in bootstrap all objects are instantiated, objects by it selves can now begin to function.

**Q:** In the example: I'm creating an EventDispatcher. Whoever needs to do something either on `doneBuild` or `beforeTerminate`, is injected with `BootstrapEventDispatcher`. Is there another way to do this?

I begin to think `EventDispatcher` is overkill (for `bootstrap` only), and maybe implement something like: [CodeIgniter:Hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Any help is appreciated.

Example bootstrap (pseudo-code):

```
function bootstrap($file = 'file.xml'){
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->log('bootstrap: init');

    $dispatcher = new BootstrapEventDispatcher($logger);

    $container = new DIContainer(new ConfigReader($file), $logger);
    $container->manualAdd('_logger', $logger);
    $container->manualAdd('_bootstrap_event_dispatcher', $dispatcher);
    $container->build();
    $dispatcher->doneBuild(null, new EventArgs());

    $dispatcher->beforeTerminate(null, new EventArgs());
    $logger->log('bootstrap: terminate');
}
class DIContainer{
    public function build(){
        //read xmls and create classes, etc.
        $this->logger->log('DIContainer: creating objects: {objects}');
    }
}
```

Example of an xml:

```
<!-- example file.xml !-->
<services>
    <service id="simple_class" class="SimpleClass"></service>
    <service id="complex_class" class="ComplexClass">
        <argument type="service" id="simple_class" /> <!-- dependency injection !-->
        <argument type="service" id="_logger" /> <!-- dependency injection !-->
        <argument type="service" id="_bootstrap_event_dispatcher" /> <!-- dependency injection !-->
    </service>
</services>
```

Example of ComplexClass:

```
class ComplexClass{
    public function __construct(SimpleClass $simpleClass, BootstrapEventDispatcher $dispatcher, Logger $logger){
        $this->simpleClass = $simpleClass;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $dispatcher->onDoneBuild(array($this, 'onBootstrapDoneBuild'));
    }
    public function onBootstrapDoneBuild($obj, $args){
        //do something.
        $this->logger->log('complexclass: did something');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the existing DIC implementations such as Pimple? (http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/)  Might give you some ideas.  Both logger and your dispatcher should be created by the container itself when needed.  Silex (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html) is a micro framework whose main application class extends Pimple.  It might give you some ideas on how to bootstrap things.

Comment: I'm looking at Silex and understanding how they do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding in Silex/Symfony2, is that there is no 'magical way' to do these type of things.

For my **first** question: It is allowed to add objects that are created before the container.

In Symfony2, in `Kernel:initializeContainer` function, Kernel adds itself to the container (`$this->container->set('kernel', $this);`) and later on, in the xml files, services are injected with Kernel (`<argument id="kernel" type="service" />`).

In Silex, `Application:__construct` function creates and adds objects to the container. `Application` injects itself to the `ServiceProviders`, so these providers can inject dependencies to their objects and add them to the container.

`$container->manualAdd('_logger', $logger);` **is correct**.

---

For my **second** question: depends on how I want to handle it. I came up with 3 options:

**.1** For C#-event-like, `Kernel` is added into the container:

In ComplexClass: `kernel.terminate += kernelTerminate`

**.2** EventDispatcher (as long as `EventDispatcher` class doesn't need dependencies that are created in the xml files)

```
//bootstrap function:
$dispatcher = new KernelEventDispatcher();
$kernel = new Kernel($dispatcher);
$container->manualAdd('_kernel.dispatcher');
```

.

```
<!-- in file.xml:ComplexClass !-->
<argument id="_kernel.dispatcher" type="service" />
```

**.3** Create an object that implements an interface: (I couldn't find another name for `Runnable`)

```
<!-- in file.xml !-->
<service id="complex_class_runnable" class="ComplexClassRunnable">
    <argument type="service" id="complex_class" />
    <argument type="service" id="_kernel" />
</service>
```

.

```
//in ComplexClassRunnable
$kernel->addRunnable($this);
```

.

```
//in Kernel
foreach($this->runnables as $runnable){
    $runnable->init(); //same for terminate
}
```

Bootstrap updated:

```
function bootstrap($file = 'file.xml'){
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->log('bootstrap: init');

    $kernel = new Kernel($logger);
    $container = new DIContainer(new ConfigReader($file), $logger);

    $container->manualAdd('_kernel', $kernel);
    $container->manualAdd('_logger', $logger);
    $container->build();

    $kernel->boot();

    $logger->log('bootstrap: terminate');
}
class DIContainer{
    public function build(){
        //read xmls and create classes, etc.
        $this->logger->log('DIContainer: creating objects: {objects}');
    }
}
class Kernel{
    public function boot(){
        //...
    }
}
```